# An identity for the elliptic theta function

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

For real $s>0$, let
$$S(s):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2/(2s^2)}
=\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-1/(2 s^2)}\right),$$
where $\vartheta$ is the elliptic theta function.

Plotting suggests that the identity
\begin{equation}
    S(s)=s\sqrt{2\pi} 
\end{equation}
is true at least for $s\ge3/2$. Is it indeed?

This conjecture, with a plot, appeared as a part of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/397437/36721), but seems to warrant separate posting.  Mathematica cannot prove or disprove this identity.

Comment: if it holds for $s \ge 3/2$, then it must hold for $s > 0$ (holomorphic extension).

Comment: No, the equality you wrote doesn’t hold exactly, although it probably looks like it numerically because the error is exponentially small as $s\to \infty$, e.g. by Euler-Maclaurin or complex analysis (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719401/euler-maclaurin-summation-for-e-x2).

Comment: In Mathematica, `With[{s=2},N[EllipticTheta[3,0,E^(-1/(2s^2))]/(s Sqrt[2Pi]),50]]` gives the answer `1.0000000000000000000000000000000001024500455847086`

Comment: To add to my comment, you can probably see the non-equality and understand the smallness of the error even more explicitly by using Poisson summation.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To give an answer, adding to my comments, your formula doesn’t hold true, although the error is exponentially small as $s\to \infty$, as can be seen by Poisson summing, which transforms your sum to
$$\sqrt{2\pi}s\left(1+\mathcal{O}(e^{-2\pi^2 s^2})\right).$$

Comment: I don't get it. How did you answer the question? You just said the identity is false, but you didn't explain why...

Comment: By Poisson summation, you can show that $S(s) -\sqrt{2\pi}s=\sqrt{2\pi}s\sum_{n\neq 0} e^{-2\pi^2 n^2 s^2} \neq 0$, which also explains why equality seems to hold numerically, because the right hand side is exponentially small (up to an overall factor of $s$ in front).